# Wildfly servers are not listed in eclipseIDE 2021-06

Tags: eclipse, ide, wildfly, wildfly-10, jboss-tools

I am using EclipseIDE 2021-06 , Wildfly server 21.02. and jdk-11.0.14.0.1
Due to system restrictions unable to download it from eclipse market place. Also no link is working whlie trying installing new software in eclipse.

How can I get the wildfly server listed in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. but it's still possible to download a server manually and use the same "new server" wizard to use it.
Simply browse to the correct directory after selecting the wildfly version in the wizard.